# What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{CP}^6$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

Using certain integrality theorem I am obtaining that $\mathbb{CP}^6$ cannot be embedded in a
Euclidean space of dimension 19 or less.

Also it is well known that $\mathbb{CP}^6$ can be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^{23}$.

Then my question is:

What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{CP}^6$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: See the results cited from older papers gathered in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602472

Comment: The paper by Davis in the other comment says that $\Bbb {CP}^6$ cannot be immersed in $\Bbb R^{21}$. The author recalls in theorem 1.5 a result by Mukherjee according to which $\Bbb {CP}^6$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^{22}$.